# how to skip foreach loop when value match in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Actually i have three foreach loop.I want to skip the second foreach loop when third foreach loop value($val == $test) match.
This is my code.

```
  <tbody>
   <?php foreach ($tests as $test): ?>
    <tr>
     <td><?= $test; ?></td>
     <?php foreach ($room as $key => $value): ?>
      <?php foreach ($value['dates'] as $val) : ?>
       <?php if ($val == $test) { ?>
        <td><span class="text-danger"><?= $value['room_id'];?</span></td>
       <?php } ?>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
     <td><span class="text-custom"><?= $value['room_id']; ?></span></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
   </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: @Saty isn't it `continue` ?

Comment: you means, if $val == $test then it should go to first foreach means $room one is it ?

Comment: I'd lose the third loop completely - as the only difference is the class name. Look at using something like `in_array` to see if `$test` exists in `$value['dates']` - then alter the class if so.

Comment: Yeah @rahul_m if $val == $test then

Comment: You have 3 nested foreach loops in that code snippet. 
Your criteria in the question was that the second loop was skipped if $val == $test. However, $val is created inside the third loop, so that's impossible. Did you mean the $value variable from the second loop?

Comment: @PedroLobito correct . My bad!!

Comment: @PedroLobito, if it is `continue` I think we should go for `continue 2`. `break` should work

Comment: @shalder : Check once answer, may be you are looking for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still maintain you've no need for the third loop. You can remove this and replace it with `in_array()`, then alter the class name depending on the result.

```
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($tests as $test): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $test; ?></td>
        <?php 
          foreach ($room as $key => $value):
              $class = "text-custom";
              if(in_array($test, $value['dates']) {
                  $class = "text-danger";
              }

             <td><span class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?= $value['room_id'];?</span></td>

         <?php endforeach; ?>
     </tr>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>
```

Couple of points - you could make this cleaner by using a ternary `if` statement - and also be careful when using short tags (`<?= ?>`) as they're not always supported by servers.

Comment: thank to you @@@@thebluefox ....you are solved my project.....thank you thank you thank you..

Comment: My pleasure @shalder

Answer (score 0):

```
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($tests as $test): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $test; ?></td>
        <?php
        $bool = FALSE;
        foreach ($room as $key => $value):
            ?>
            <?php foreach ($value['dates'] as $val) : ?>
                <?php if ($val == $test) { ?>
                    <td><span class="text-danger"><?= $value['room_id']; ?></span></td>
                    <?php
                    $bool = TRUE;
                    break;
                }
                ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <td><span class="text-custom"><?= $value['room_id']; ?></span></td>

            <?php
            if ($bool) {
                continue;
            }

        endforeach;
        ?>
    </tr>
    <?php
endforeach;
?>
```

Use This Code I applied **Break;** on second loop on the basis third loop condition.Hope This will work for you

Comment: actually it's not working for me properly ..thanks for helping

Comment: Now use i replaced break with continue

Answer (score 0):

you can use `continue`. If you want to skip nested loop then you can write `continue`**`n`**, where n is number of nested loop you want to skip.

**`continue`** will skip the iteration.

**`break`** will end loop.